# Cannot Move Messages in Mail.app

Tags: mail.app

On the first of January every year, I move the previous year's mails from INBOX, to 'all', which is an actual 'physical' folder in Mail.app - in other words, off the server and onto my Mac.  I do this by selecting the last message of 31 December, and then scrolling to the 1 January of the previous year, and holding down SHIFT whilst I select that message.  I then right-click on the selected mails, and choose 'move to' and 'all'.

In 2018, there are over 13,000 messages, so when I perform the above operation, I wait for a little while.  They appear to have vanished from INBOX, which is good.  I click on ‘Sent’, intending to do the same with 2018’s messages in there.  But if I switch back to INBOX, hey presto – nothing has been moved.  Worse, if I go and look in ‘all’, I see copies of the messages that I thought I had moved.   If I did it ten times, there would be ten copies of those e-mails.

I know that there is also a ‘copy’ option on the contextual menu, but I do not click on that.  I click on ‘move’.

Why are my messages not moving?

Comment: Are you using iCloud and the messages are being replaced?

Comment: No, iCloud is not active.